# Detecting a url using preg_match? without http:// in the string

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match

I was wondering how I could check a string broken into an array against a preg_match to see if it started with www. I already have one that check for http://www.

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}

$stringToArray = explode(" ",$_POST['text']);

  foreach($stringToArray as $key=>$val){
  $urlvalid = isValidURL($val);
  if($urlvalid){
  $_SESSION["messages"][] = "NO URLS ALLOWED!";
  header("Location: http://www.domain.com/post/id/".$_POST['postID']);
     exit();
     }
     }
```

Thanks!
Stefan

Comment: Can you show some code you have tried based on the one that does work? More people here will help you solve a problem you're working on that give you the answer. Just getting a requirement and producing an answer is what I get paid to do.

Comment: added in the working code so far

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want something like:

```
%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i
```

this is using the | to match either `http://` or `www` at the beginning. I changed the delimiter to `%` to avoid clashing with the `|`

Comment: this is not true... the second group is `(www\.)` which requires a `.` after `www.`. also, i tested the regexp against 'wwwtumblr.com' here: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php and it did not pass.

however, this *will* match something like www.tumblrcom. the biggest error is probably the unescaped `.` in the third group. these days i usually do `([a-z0-9-]\.)+([a-z0-9-])` to match the subdomains and the tld.

Answer (score 10):

John Gruber of Daring Fireball has posted a very comprehensive regex for all types of URLs that may be of interest.  You can find it here:

http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: How looks the actual code? I have string $str = "Blaa lorem ipsum domain-name.studio blaa blaa another.com blaa blaa"; and I want to get output:

Yes it contains one or more domains:
domain-name.studio
another.com

Thanks if you have time to help!

Comment: I tried: $found_url = "";
 if(preg_match("~^$regex$~i", $description, $m)) $found_url = $m;
 if(preg_match("~^$regex$~i", $description, $m)) $found_url .= $m;
But got error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ','

Answer (score 1):

I explode the string at first as the url might be half way through it e.g. `hello how are you www.google.com`

Explode the string and use a `foreach` statement.

Eg:

```
$string = "hello how are you www.google.com";
$string = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($string as $word){
  if ( (strpos($word, "http://") === 0) || (strpos($word, "www.") === 0) ){
  // Code you want to excute if string is a link
  }
}
```

Note you have to use the `===` operator because `strpos` can return, will return a `0` which will appear to be `false`.

Comment: How would you extract the link only?

Answer (score 1):

I used this below which allows you to detect url's anywhere in a string. For my particular application it's a contact form to combat spam so no url's are allowed. Works very well.

Link to resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/

My implementation;

```
<?php
// Validate message
if(isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] == 'Include your order number here if relevant...') {
$messageError = "Required";
} else {
$message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}
if (strlen($message) > 1000) {
$messageError = "1000 chars max";
}
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message)) {
$messageError = "Url's not allowed";
}

// Validate data
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Limiting TLD from 2 upto 3 characters is really poor, see: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Answer (score -2):

Try `implode($myarray, '').strstr("www.")==0`. That implodes your array into one string, then checks whether `www.` is at the beginning of the string (index 0).

Comment: I explode the string at first as the url might be half way through it e.g. hello how are you www.google.com