# PHP search a string for http:// or www

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting a url using preg_match? without  in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762260/detecting-a-url-using-preg-match-without-http-in-the-string)

I wanting to search a string that is input by the user, for instances of http:// if one is found I want to wrap the link in the correct html,

so for example, the following could be input by a user,

```
 Google's url is http://www.google.com,
```

what I want to save that as it,

```
 Google's url is <a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com</a>
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. If you remove the irrelevant `codeigniter` tag, some more of the previous answers to this topic might show up in the related links.

Comment: simple preg replace..... just google for domain / url regex and then do some `<a>$1</a>`

Answer (score 3):

```
function make_clickable($sText) {
    $sClickText = str_replace(' www.', ' http://www.', $sText);
    $sClickText = preg_replace("/([\s])?(http|ftp|https)([\:\/\/])([^\s]+)/i", " <a href=\"$2$3$4\" target=\"_blank\">$2$3$4</a>",$sClickText);
    return $sClickText;
}
```

Tadaa!

Comment: I guess you´ve got this working, but shoudn´t `([\:\/\/])` be `(\:\/\/)` as you version looks for a `:` or a `/` (twice the same character in the character group)?