# Catch the first image from post_meta instead of post_content

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

here is a good article about this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/

but in the article explains how to catch the first image from the content

```
$output = preg_match_all('https://cdn.css-tricks.com/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

is there any way to check for the custom field instead of content?

because I dont use `the_content();` but Im using

```
$photo_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_custom_field', true);
echo $photo_gallery
```

so my question is how to catch the first image in $photo_gallery

Below is a try but didnt work

```
function catch_that_image() {
   global $post;
   $first_img = '';
   ob_start();
   ob_end_clean();
   $custom_content = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_custom_field', false);
   $output = preg_match_all('/[\w\-]+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/', $custom_content, $matches);
   $first_img = $matches[1][0];

   if(empty($first_img)) {
        $first_img = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/images/noimage.png';
   }

   return $first_img;
 }
```

I changed preg_match to `/[\w\-]+\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)/` because I have images as url in the custom content but I see noimage.png instead. Still not working

Should I use global $wpdb instead of global $post ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have more than one image stored as custom field (post meta) with name 'my_custom_field', right?

```
$photo_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_custom_field', true);
```

`true` means return last value entered. If you change it into `false` you will get all images and this way you can get first one:

```
$photo_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_custom_field', false);
$first_photo = $photo_gallery[0];
```

Comment: No this custom field we can say that Im using as a content because the_content(); is used for the description so instead of catching the first image from the post content I want to search it in this custom field section

Comment: Just updated my first post I have tried as you told me but didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change with `$photo_gallery`, 
in the

`$output = preg_match_all('https://yourdomain.com/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $photo_gallery, $matches);`

You can debug `print_r($photo_gallery);` and see if your `$photo_gallery` is the content you want.

Comment: Simeon $photo_gallery is just a custom field that Im using as a custom c ontent so the_content(); is used for a description in my theme and I would like to catch the first image from this custom field instead the post content I tried your explantion but didnt work.Thanks for your reply

Comment: Im wrong in the preg_match_all because my images are not in img tags but just as url in the custom content

Comment: You need to preg_match for URLs instead.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762260/detecting-a-url-using-preg-match-without-http-in-the-string.

Comment: yes but there are multiple urls in different formats I need only jpg and png formats

Comment: but the problem is not there because it shows me allways the default image Im not sure if its searching in custom field or not, i tried the same pregmatch that you told me in the link above

Comment: Then change the preg_match:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143202/any-preg-match-to-extract-image-urls-from-text

Comment: thanks but before the preg match the problem is another one.As u see I have used $custom_content variable instead of $post->post_content, if I want to catch the image from the post content it works but when i use custom_content it doesnt work.My question is simple.I want tocatch the first image in the custom content based in custom field

Comment: Hi Gazi, please, can you share the output of this `print_r($matches)` to see what is in the array?